# Cannot run python 3.5 along with python 2.7.4 in Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, python-3.5, python-install

I am trying to install Python 3.5.0 alongside with Python 2.7.4.

```
C:\Users\Animesh>python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\Animesh>py
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\Animesh>py -2
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:55:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\Animesh>py -3
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "E:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00003514 (most recent call first):
```

I tried a bunch of commands as shown above but python 3.5 does not seem to work. I even tried creating a project on PyCharm using the Python 3.5 interpreter but it gives that same error.

How should I rectify this error?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.5?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I used the official installer for windows.

Comment: Are there 2 separate file paths for 2.7 and 3.5?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax I have only env. variable `PYTHONPATH` that has all paths for python 2.7

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax
`C:\Users\Animesh>echo %PYTHONPATH%
E:\Python27;E:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;E:\Python27\Lib;E:\Python27\DLLs;E:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;`

Comment: Then it didn't get installed correctly. You should have to file paths try reinstalling python 3.5 and create a new path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official installer for Python will install 3.5 in `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5`.

It will automatically add this path to your `PATH` variable (if you tell it). It seems like you did not enable this option.

In your `PATH` (not `PYTHONPATH`) setting.

You can get to this by going to the Settings application and searching for environment, then clicking on "Edit environment variables for your account" - this will open a properties window; click `Environment Variables` on the bottom to load the settings for your account.

You need to add the path manually to the `PATH` variable, and remove the `E:\Python2.7` path.

Do this, then restart your command prompt and the default Python version will be 3.5.

For PyCharm, you can just add a new local interpreter in settings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and point it directly to the location where you installed Python 3.5.

---

Since both interpreters are named `python.exe`, the first one found in your `PATH` will be executed. In practical terms this means, whatever is in your `PATH` is the default Python for your system. To execute the other version, you need to point to it explicitly.

If you have Python 2.7 in `E:\Python2.7` and Python 3.5 in `C:\Program Files\Python 3.5`, pick the one you want to be the default and add the path to it in your `PATH` environment variable - you can always refer to the other installation by typing the full path to the `python.exe` file.

```
C:\>python.exe # this will launch whatever is found first in your `PATH`
C:\>E:\Python2.7\python.exe  # explicitly launch the 2.7 version.
```

As far as PyCharm is concerned, it will read `PATH` and pick up the default interpreter, you can add the other one in your settings by browsing to its location.

Then, when creating a new project, you can pick which version you want to work with.

Comment: Maybe you should add something about how to run a program on either version by opening up the specific version idle then opening the program from there. :)

Comment: So, does this mean python 2 and 3 cannot coexist?

Comment: No, they can - but only one can be the default - which, by the way, is the same for Windows, Linux, and OSX.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I removed python 2.7 paths from `PATH` but this error does not seem to go away. Have a look [here](https://anotepad.com/notes/hemgcj).

Comment: Get rid of your `PYTHONPATH` variable in your environment.

Comment: Yes that did the job. I can use python 2.7 using `py -2` and python 3.5 using `py -3`